# Delete LastRow to LastRow

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet were a user can enter the amount of rows that will be used (I have code that will expand or decrease a table size). When the amount of rows the user inputs is less then the current number of rows in the table, I want to delete all the rows that are not being used. I'm using LastRow for this at the moment. I have a LastRow at the beginning of the code and at the end, so I know perfectly well which rows I want to delete, but I can't get the macro right. I think the code should be something like the following:

```
LastRowFirst = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
LastRowNext = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

Range("B" & LastRowFirst : "AA" & LastRowNext).Delete
```

The total code i'm using is the following:

```
    LastRowFirst = Worksheets("Ent. Description").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = True

    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheetName As String
    targetSheetName = "Ent. Description"
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(targetSheetName)
   
    Dim newTableRows As Long
    Dim newTableRowsCellAdd As String
    newTableRowsCellAdd = "A1"
    newTableRows = targetSheet.Range(newTableRowsCellAdd).Value2

    Dim targetTable As ListObject
    Dim targetTableName As String
    targetTableName = "Table1"
    Set targetTable = targetSheet.ListObjects(targetTableName)

    Dim newTableRange As Range
    Set newTableRange = targetTable.Range.Resize(newTableRows + 1, targetTable.Range.Columns.Count)
    targetTable.Resize newTableRange
    
    Dim tableCell As Range
    Dim rowWithFormulas As Long
    rowWithFormulas = 1
    For Each tableCell In targetTable.ListRows(rowWithFormulas).Range
    
        If tableCell.HasFormula Then
        
            tableCell.Copy targetTable.ListColumns(tableCell.Column).DataBodyRange
        
        End If
    
    Next tableCell

    LastRowNext = Worksheets("ent. Description").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
```

If you have any further questions please let me know

Comment: What about `Range("B" & LastRowFirst : "AA" & LastRowNext).EntireRow.Delete`?

Comment: Do you want to delete the entire rows or clear the contents in those cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added code for both clearing the range contents and deleting the entire rows.

I suggest that you use `Option Explicit` at the top of your modules.

Read the code's comments and choose one of the methods (clear or delete) no need of both

EDIT: Just changed the `.clearcontents` with `.clear` so formatting is also deleted

```
Public Sub ResizeTable()
    
    Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = True

    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheetName As String
    targetSheetName = "Ent. Description"
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(targetSheetName)
   
    Dim newTableRows As Long
    Dim newTableRowsCellAdd As String
    newTableRowsCellAdd = "A1"
    newTableRows = targetSheet.Range(newTableRowsCellAdd).Value2

    Dim targetTable As ListObject
    Dim targetTableName As String
    targetTableName = "Table1"
    Set targetTable = targetSheet.ListObjects(targetTableName)
    
    ' Find the table's last row before resizing
    Dim previousLastRow As Long
    previousLastRow = targetTable.HeaderRowRange.Row + targetTable.Range.Rows.Count - 1

    Dim newTableRange As Range
    Set newTableRange = targetTable.Range.Resize(newTableRows + 1, targetTable.Range.Columns.Count)
    targetTable.Resize newTableRange
    
    ' Find the table's last row after resizing
    Dim newlastRow As Long
    newlastRow = targetTable.HeaderRowRange.Row + targetTable.Range.Rows.Count
    
    ' Clear range contents and formatting
    targetSheet.Range(targetSheet.Cells(newlastRow, targetTable.Range.Cells(1).Column).Address, targetSheet.Cells(previousLastRow, targetTable.Range.Cells(targetTable.Range.Columns.Count).Column).Address).Clear
    
    ' Delete all rows in range
    targetSheet.Range(targetSheet.Cells(newlastRow, targetTable.Range.Cells(1).Column).Address, targetSheet.Cells(previousLastRow, targetTable.Range.Cells(targetTable.Range.Columns.Count).Column).Address).EntireRow.Delete
    
    Dim tableCell As Range
    Dim rowWithFormulas As Long
    rowWithFormulas = 1
    For Each tableCell In targetTable.ListRows(rowWithFormulas).Range
    
        If tableCell.HasFormula Then
        
            tableCell.Copy targetTable.ListColumns(tableCell.Column).DataBodyRange
        
        End If
    
    Next tableCell
    
End Sub
```

Give it a try and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, it does delete/ clear the formulas and resize the table, but it does not change the formatting of the cells now outside the table. I would like clear all/ delete all rows so there is no formatting and the scroll bare is minimised to the end of the table. Would you be able to help?

Comment: Just changed the `.clearcontents` with `.clear` so formatting is also deleted. Code is updated. Remember to mark the answer so others may find it. And also just pick one of the two, clear the range or delete the rows. Glad it helped!